# How to resolve ticket expired error on Mac OS connecting to MS Sql Server using trusted connection

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, kerberos

I am trying to connect to MS Sql Server using python and sqlalchemy, with trusted connection / active directory / kerberos authentication.  I was able to connect before, but now I am getting this error:

```
Error: ('HY000', u'[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: Ticket expired (negative cache) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by running `kinit` in terminal with no options.